# Python argparse nargs='+' trying to pass in multiple strings but script is not picking up strings after first one

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have a Python file (python 3.6) that I would like to be able to take a series of file names in a single argument. I am trying to do so like this

```
parser.add_argument('--ftr', type=str, required=True, nargs='+',
                    help='a list of files to read, in order passed')
dargs, leftover = parser.parse_known_args()
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

but when I run my command

```
python reader.py --ftr=file1.py file2.py
```

I get back

```
(Pdb) dargs
Namespace(ftr=['file1.py'])
```

How can it be made so that I can get back

```
Namespace(ftr=['file1.py', 'file2.py'])
```

?

Comment: The '--flag=value' only works for one value.  Once it's processed 'value', it moves on to the next argument.  In your case 'file2.py' probably appears in `leftovers`.  The code that handles the '=' syntax is separate, so the two can't be combined as you attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print the help text for your parser you can see how you are expected to supply your arguments:

```
usage: reader.py [-h] --ftr FTR [FTR ...]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --ftr FTR [FTR ...]
```

Your command should be:

```sh
~ python reader.py --ftr file1.py file2.py
```

Comment: I have up-voted your answer in favor of mine since I think that using the help option is more generally useful than just telling them what is wrong. Can I suggest that you edit your answer to include invoking their program the -h/--help option that got you the usage info above? That would help the beginners that do not realize that the parser automatically provides the --help option. Those asking the kind of question above are the ones most likely to not know about this feature and that knowledge would likely allow them to resolve it themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your command line syntaxt is incorrect.

```
python reader.py --ftr=file1.py file2.py
```

Try leaving out the **=** sign afte the long argument name like this:

```
python reader.py --ftr file1.py file2.py
```